# Android Studio Gradle NullPointerException each restart

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gradle, android-studio

I'm struggling with a `Gradle: : java.lang.NullPointerException` message each time I restart Android Studio. The solution is to remove all facets from the Modules section, add them once again and rebuild the project. The problem is I have to do this each time I launch Android Studio along with my project. How do I solve this problem?

The project was imported from an Eclipse project, and Gradle is configured probably fine (I'm using a local distribution and have set path to its directory).

Other questions did not seem to address the reoccurence of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio is an early access preview, and bugs are to be expected. Best chance to solve the problem is to file an issue with an exact description.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that.